# Android crash when lunch after upgrading react-native 0.60

Tags: android, react-native, crash, upgrade, androidx

After upgrading react native to get it work when build 64Bits (for the last GooglePlay requirement)
I follow the guideline for upgrade, now I'm crashing at start with the following logcat error 
Android application crash on start.

Just in case, regarding org.apache.http.legacy, I added
`<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>`
in the AndroidManifest to get react-native-maps work with android 9 (it was working before the upgrade process).

**Logcat**

```
7724-7788 E/CrashLogHandler: Stack trace: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/react/views/webview/ReactWebViewManager;
        at com.planet.planet.MainApplication$1.getPackages(MainApplication.java:53)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:78)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:41)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.loadApp(ReactActivityDelegate.java:91)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onCreate(ReactActivityDelegate.java:80)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:52)
        at com.planet.planet.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.planet.planet.debug-kl4UVs7kB1DjwIuGzZwG2w==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.planet.planet
```